# Hyper-V IP Address Not Visible

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V VM running **Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise**. For some reason this VM is not displaying its IP address in the Hyper-V Manager:

[image]

The integration servers enabled on this VM are as shown below:

[image]

Other VMs on my machine are correctly displaying their IP (they're running newer OS's than WinServer2008R2). Can someone please help me fix this problem?